# Add custom list box Kendo HTML Editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

We are planning to use Kendo HTML Editor (angular ver.) in one of our app.

This will be used to create E-mail campaigns online.  This e-mail template will be personalised so need to include special strings (acting as keys) such as {$firstname}

Is it possible to add listbox in Kendo HTML Editor where we can list these keys?

This will help content editor to pickup any key from list without remembering. And on selection we can add value on cursor position.

Thank you.
Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

So if you want to implement this feature in the toolbar of your editor I would try something like this.

Step 1: Build a toolbar template.

(I can't post more than two links but if you google "**angular kendo toolbar template**" and find the first demo you'll find my example)

instead of using the anchor they use add an input inside your template.

Step 2: Turn the input into a kendo dropdownlist when the page is ready.

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dropdownlist/remotedatasource

Step 3: Add a change event to the datasource then add something like this to the dropdown you just made.

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/editor/api

you may need to tweak this a little because these examples are mostly kendo in plain js but it's a good place to start.